# stringr install error: namespace ‘stringr’ is imported by ‘bibtex’ so cannot be unloaded

Tags: r, package, installation, stringr, bibtex

Hi i am trying to install the package stringr in my R.

i tried following:

```
install.packages("stringr") 
install.packages("stringr",dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org") 
install.packages("stringr", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
```

it still give me the error:

```
Package ‘stringr’ version 1.2.0 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘stringr’ is imported by ‘bibtex’ so cannot be unloaded
```

how can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try from a fresh (i.e. close the existing session and restart) R terminal: `remove.packages("stringr"); install.packages("stringr")`

Comment: `remove.packages()` may not be necessary from a clean session ...

Comment: This might work assuming no other R sessions are open and holding the fort.